# Convertir información de un excel a base64 con python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, base64

En el programa que tengo leo un archivo excel y le hago un filtro, he intentado convertir el resultado del filtro en base64 pero me sale el siguiente error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'DataFrame'
```

Código:

```
#Importamos las bibliotecas pandas , tinys3 y io
import pandas as pd
import tinys3
import base64

# Lectura del archivo
Disp = pd.read_excel('PS9InventKOF.xlsx','OK',usecols=['UO','Estatus_Equipo','Estatus_Eq_Disponible','Estatus_Enfriador ','No_Ptas', 'Estatus_Enf_KOF', 'Tipo_Uso', 'Categoria'])

# Filtrado del archivo
Disponible = Disp[ ( Disp.UO.isin(['TLALNEPANTLA']) ) & ( Disp.Estatus_Equipo.isin(['DISPONIBLE']) )  & ( Disp.Estatus_Eq_Disponible.isin(['NUEVO','USADO']) ) & ( Disp.No_Ptas.isin(['1','2','3']) ) & ( Disp.Categoria.isin(['Pequeño','Mediano', 'Grande', 'Extra Grande']) ) ]

print (Disponible)
```

la conversión es para después poder hacer un JSON.

Comment: ¿Qué pretendes exactamente? base64 no es más que una forma de codificar usando exclusivamente caracteres ASCII una serie de datos binarios arbitrarios. Se usa típicamente para poder transmitir en forma de cadena ASCII algo que es de naturaleza binaria, como una imagen, un audio, etc. En tu caso tienes un dataframe, que es más bien una tabla. Aunque internamente esa tabla está almacenada en bytes en python, a priori no te serviría de nada pasar esos bytes a base64, pues para "consumirlos" necesitarás de nuevo la conversión inversa. Repito ¿por qué quieres hacer esto?

Comment: Edite mi pregunta, espero así sea más fácil poder resolver mi duda, gracias por el comentario

Comment: Aun no se entiende porque quieres  transformar a base64, si con el método ´to_json´ ya tienes el resultado que deseas. Si solucionó tu problema la respuesta de abuldafia, recuerda marcarla como aceptada. Si no, procura darnos más información por medio de comentarios o edición de tu pregunta inicial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La pregunta parece un caso de **XY**-question, en la que el usuario tiene un problema **X** ("Quiero pasar un dataframe a JSON"), se le ocurre una solución que puede ser buena o no ("Puedo hacerlo a través de una conversión a base64"), pero cuando lo intenta se encuentra con otro problema **Y** ("¿por qué no me funciona la conversión a base64?") y entonces pregunta por el problema Y en lugar del X.

En tu caso hay que partir de que convertir un dataframe pandas a base64 es una mala idea, por razones que explicaré en un "anexo". Por lo que me centraré entonces en responder el problema X en vez del Y.

### Convertir un Dataframe a JSON

Pandas tiene un método específico para ello. Se trata de [`DataFrame.to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html), con muchas opciones para controlar la forma del JSON resultante. En el caso más simple se usaría así:

```
data_json = Disponible.to_json()
```

Deberás investigar su uso y, en todo caso, crear una nueva pregunta si encuentras problemas.

### Anexo. ¿Por qué no base64?

Base64 es en el fondo una especie de "formato binario", sólo que recodificado de forma tal que todos los bytes que lo componen corresponden a un subconjunto imprimible del código ASCII.

Aunque una cadena base64 sea puro ASCII, con un aspecto como "4AX0FJC==" por ejemplo, lo que contiene en realidad una vez decodificado es una secuencia de bytes. Qué signifique esa secuencia es en general desconocido, es un dato "opaco". Lo mismo podría tratarse de una imagen JPG que de un archivo de audio MP3, o de un fichero comprimido ZIP, o incluso de un documento excel (xlsx).

En cualquier caso, la secuencia de bytes obtenida será inútil si no sabes qué representa, o no tienes el programa adecuado para consumirla.

En tu caso, la conversión a base64 falla porque le estás pasando un objeto de tipo DataFrame, en lugar de una secuencia de bytes. Pero aún si consiguieras extraer la secuencia de bytes subyacente al dataframe y convertirla a Base64, y meter la cadena resultante en un campo de una variable JSON ¿para qué podría servir eso? Una vez recibido ese JSON y extraída la cadena base64 y decodificada de nuevo, tendrías los datos binarios de un dataframe Pandas, que no son útiles para nada salvo para el propio programa que los creó. No es una forma adecuada de compartir información.

Por otro lado, el uso de JSON sugiere que quieres compartir esos datos entre el script python y otra parte en javascript, lo cual refuerza aún más el argumento de que base64 es inútil en este caso, pues javascript no sabrá qué hacer con los bytes que han sido generados en un formato específico de Python.

Comment: Así es... Necesito mandar un JSON y eso con dataframe.to_json() lo he logrado, pero entonces ese mismo JSON no se puede o no es conveniente mandarlo en BASE64?

Comment: @LuisVera Se puede, pero ¿para qué? El JSON que has obtenido con `.to_json()` es una cadena. Como tal, es una secuencia de bytes y por tanto puede pasarse a base64. Quien lo reciba podría decodificar el base64 y obtener de nuevo el JSON original, para consumirlo desde javascript o convertirlo a otro formato. ¿Para qué el paso intermedio a base64? Lo único que se me ocurre es para "ofuscar" un poco el contenido, de modo que a primera vista no se sepa qué datos hay ahí, pero no es un verdadero cifrado. Cualquiera podría recuperar el JSON fácilmente.